# Does $\exists$ a matrix $A$ so that $\{A^p:p\geq 1\}$ spans $M_n(\mathbb R)?$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The main question is :

> (TRUE/FALSE)
>
> For any $n\geq 2,$ there exists an $n\times n$ real matrix $A$ such thatthe set $\{A^p|p\geq 1\}$ spans the $\mathbb R$ vector space $M_n(\mathbb R).$

I tried whether we can find such $A$ that the above set spans $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\right)$, $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\right)$, $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)$. But I could not go further.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Hint: use the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Comment: Show that $\text{span}\{A^k \;|\;k\ge 0\}$ is of dimension $\le n$.

Comment: Yes we can't find $n^2$ linearly independent matrices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is already false for $n=2$. By Cayley-Hamilton, $A^2-tr(A)A+\det(A)I=0$ for all $A\in M_2(K)$, so that $I,A,A^2,\ldots,$ do not span the $4$-dimensional vector space $M_2(K)$ for any $A$.

Answer (score 2):

In fact it is false for all $n\ge2$ (an even stronger statement).

By the Cayley-Hamilton theorem,  $A$ satisfies its characteristic polynomial.   This is an $n$th degree polynomial, $C_A(x)=\operatorname{det}(xI-A)=x^n+a_{n-1}A^{n-1}+\dots +a_0$.

So $C_A(A)=A^n+a_{n-1}A^{n-1}\dots+a_0=0$.

This shows that $A^n\in\operatorname{span}\{A,\dots,A^{n-1}\}$.  Thus, $\operatorname{span}\{A^p\mid p\ge1\}=\operatorname{span}\{A,\dots,A^{n-1}\}$.

So, $\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{span}\{A^p\mid p\ge1\})\lt n$.

But the dimension of $M_n(\Bbb R)$ is $n^2$.  Therefore the answer is no, since $n\ge2\implies n^2\gt n$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another proof. If $\{A^p:\ p\ge1\}$ spans $M_n(\mathbb R)$, then all matrices are polynomials in $A$ and hence they commute with $A$. Now it is a standard exercise to show that if $A$ that commutes with all matrices, $A$ must be a scalar matrix. Yet, clearly, when $n\ge2$, if $A$ is a scalar matrix, the linear span of $\{A^p:\ p\ge1\}$ is at most the set of all scalar matrices. It cannot possibly be the set of all square matrices.